# Java generic 3-median quicksort

Tags: java, array, quick-sort

My generic 3 median quicksort:

```
public class Util {

    final static int CUTOFF = 27;

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quicksort(T[] a) {
        quicksort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quicksort(T[] a, int low, int high) {
        if (low + CUTOFF > high) {
            insertionSort(a);
        } else {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if (a[middle].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
                swapReferences(a, low, middle);
            }
            if (a[high].compareTo(a[low]) < 0) {
                swapReferences(a, low, high);
            }
            if (a[high].compareTo(a[middle]) < 0) {
                swapReferences(a, middle, high);
            }
            swapReferences(a, middle, high - 1);
            T pivote = a[high - 1];
            int i, j;
            for (i = low, j = high - 1;;) {
                while (a[++i].compareTo(pivote) < 0);
                while (pivote.compareTo(a[--j]) < 0);
                if (i >= j) {
                    break;
                }
                swapReferences(a, i, j);
            }
            swapReferences(a, i, high - 1);
            quicksort(a, low, i - 1);
            quicksort(a, i + 1, high);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void swapReferences(T a[], int x, int y) {
        T temp = a[x];
        a[x] = a[y];
        a[y] = temp;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertionSort(T a[]) {
        for (int p = 1; p < a.length; p++) {
            T tmp = a[p];
            int j = p;
            for (; j > 0 && tmp.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0; j--) {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
            }
            a[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

}
```

My testing code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PruebaTiempo {

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(T a[], T x) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            int cmp = a[mid].compareTo(x);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int linearSearch(T a[], T x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].compareTo(x) == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rd = new Random();
        long t1, t2;
        for (int k = 50000; k <= 1000000; k += 50000) {
            int arr[] = rd.ints(k, 10000, 1000000).toArray();
            Integer array[] = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
            Integer array2[]=Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Util.quicksort(array);
            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Tiempo quicksort: " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(array2);
            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Tiempo sort: " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
        }

    }
}
```

I know they are different sorts, but they should have similar running times.
In my PC the results are:

```
Tiempo quicksort: 1663ms
Tiempo sort: 21ms
Tiempo quicksort: 14986ms
Tiempo sort: 71ms
Tiempo quicksort: 27422ms
Tiempo sort: 186ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in this line:

```
 if (low + CUTOFF > high) {
            insertionSort(a);
```

It should had been

```
if (low + CUTOFF > high) {
            insertionSort(a,low,high);
```

And the corresponding change to insertionSort